# Memory issues with cocoa touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management

First let me start off by saying I do not believe I am leaking, but I could be wrong. My issue is that at after my app is done loading I have about 10 - 20 mb of Live bytes according to object alloc, which I am fine with. However, according to activity monitor my process allocation is about 70 - 80 mb, which needless to say is a bit high. To make matters worse when I go on to load the next screen of my app I need to pull more data to build it, which then sends my process allocation up to 100 mb+ or so, need less to say this is much to high and the next action after this causes my app to crash due to low memory warnings. Is there anyway to reduce the process allocation memory?

Comment: Have you run build and analyse? that would be my first place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Belief can sometimes be validated with cold hard data. Have you tried using [Leaks](http://www.mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/)? Allocations is another helpful memory profiling performance tool provided by Instruments. The way to reduce memory allocation is to not use as much. ;-)

What are you allocating that takes up 100+ MB? Images? Video?

The question is, are you releasing memory when you're done with it. Instruments can help you answer that question. If you show some code, the community can try to help you troubleshoot as well.

Best regards.